# Solving $f - Af_z + Bf_{zz} = g$ with partial integration

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

I am wondering how to solve the following differential equation for $f$

$ f - A\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f + B \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}f = g, $

where $f$ and $g$ are functions and $A$ and $B$ are known constants.

Previously I had the equation

$ f - A\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f  = g, $

which I dealt with by using an integration of parts to get f on the left-hand side and an integral on the right-hand side, so I was wondering if one could do something similar with the second-order equation (I don't really mind what the form of the right-hand side as).

Comment: The second equation is called a [separable differentiation equation](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Separable.aspx), which can be solved as you described. The first equation is _not_ separable, and cannot be solved simply by integration. Rather, it is a second-order non-homogeneous linear ODE. You may find [this set of notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/IntroSecondOrder.aspx) helpful for solving it.

Comment: I should state that f can depend on $x$, $y$ and $z$, so surely it is not an ODE, would that change the method of solution in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f - A\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f + B \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}f = g,$$
It's a linear differential inhomogeneous equation  of second order with constant coefficients. The solution will depend on the value of the coeffcients $A,B$. The solution of the homogeneous equation is:
$$Bf''-Af'+f = 0$$
$$f(z,t)=c_1(t)e^{\alpha z }+c_2(t)e^{\beta z}$$
Where $\alpha, \beta$ are solutions of the characteristic equation of the DE ( I suppose the roots are distincts for simplicity):
$$Br^2-Ar+1=0$$
Then you have to solve the inhomogeneous equation. That particular solution will depend on the function $g$. The general solution of the DE will be the sum of the homogeneous solution and the particular one.

Comment: $f$ can depend on $x$, $y$ and $z$, so does that mean one needs arbitrary functions of $x$ and $y$ in front of the exponential terms in the solution to the homogeneous equation?

Comment: Oh I see. I supposed the function $f$ only depends on $t, z$ but if it depends on three variables $z, x, y$ then the constants depends on $x,y$ and are functions of these variables @tom

Comment: Would it be possible to determine the values of those constants so they are not arbitrary functions. I have a boundary condition for $f$ when $z=0$ and a continuity equation, could both of these be used to find the constants, or does one find the values of the constants when one obtains the particular solution?

Comment: @Tom yes of course you can use initial conditions or whatever is given to determine the functions $c_1(x,y),c_2(x,y)$